# Postgresql update performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

We have a table which stores about 20 million records:

```
                     Table "public.tbl"
         Column          |            Type             | Modifiers
-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id                      | uuid                        | not null
 a                       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 b                       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 c                       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 d                       | timestamp without time zone |
 e                       | integer                     |
 f                       | integer                     |
 g                       | uuid                        |
 h                       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 j                       | uuid                        | not null
 k                       | uuid                        | not null
 l                       | character varying(32)       |
 m                       | boolean                     | not null
 n                       | boolean                     |
 o                       | boolean                     |
Indexes:
    "pk_table" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_table_k" btree k)
    "idx_table_j" btree (j)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_table_k" FOREIGN KEY (k) REFERENCES z(id)
    "fk_table_j" FOREIGN KEY (j) REFERENCES y(id)
Referenced by:
<....>


 select count(*) from tbl;
  count   
----------
 20594896
(1 row)


  oid  | table_schema | table_name | row_estimate | total_bytes | index_bytes | toast_bytes | table_bytes | total |  index  | toast |  table
-------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------+---------
 16532 | public       | tbl  |  2.09275e+07 | 13775568896 |  5316452352 |             |  8459116544 | 13 GB | 5070 MB |       | 8067 MB
```

And we wanted to run a single query:

```
update tbl set o=false where o is null;
```

On a slow testing Google Cloud Sql Machine (1vcpu, 3.75mb ram, 100gb storage) this query took ~3 hours.

The best we could get to was ~23 minutes by increasing disk throughput. 
Logs were also full of message like these:

```
[3091] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
[3091] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (5 seconds apart)
[3091] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
[3091] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (5 seconds apart)
[3091] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
[3091] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (5 seconds apart)
[3091] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
```

Since we cannot tune those params on CloudSQL, we've launched a simple Debian based machine (4 vCPUs, 15 GB, 500GB storage) with PG9.6 By setting `max_wal_size` to 20GB and `checkpoint_timeout` to 50 min we got down to ~19 minutes

```
explain analyze update tbl set j=false where j is null;
QUERY PLAN     

 Update on tbl  (cost=0.00..1720212.95 rows=59869756 width=133) (actual time=1193435.444..1193435.444 rows=0 
loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..1720212.95 rows=59869756 width=133) (actual time=0.039..69547.781 rows=20
142544 loops=1)
         Filter: (j IS NULL)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 452352
 Planning time: 0.725 ms
 Execution time: 1193435.523 ms
(6 rows)
```

Looking at `top` cpu is at ~20% iowait so I guess we are hitting iops or disk throughput limit.

Anyway to improve this, or how to troubleshoot that? Or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: If it's one time operation, and you accept the risk, you may try alter table to UNLOGGED , perform update, and then switch it back to LOGGED.

Comment: moving to max io performance google vm (io wait was 0-2%), setting unlogged and testing without where clause got us to ~11 minutes.

Comment: Dropping the index `idx_table_j` would certainly speed up things

Comment: `update tbl set j=false where j is null;` whereas `j` is an UUID?

Comment: You say there are 20594896 rows in the table? And yet, Postgres estimates 59869756 rows in the seq scan? How many rows are there with `o is null` or `j is null`? And which is it now? Please review your whole question and set things straight.

Comment: Tuning the query could affect the retrieve of the record (i.e., using indexes) or the writing of new data (i.e., wal write frequences). There are many parameters you might change. The first question is: how many rows have `o` (or `j`) `NULL`?